# Calling Windows SDK GetGlyphIndices from VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, interop

I am calling `GetGlyphIndices` from Vb.Net. I am using a single character string. I get the correct value in the indices array for the character `6` but not for characters requiring 2 bytes to be returned.

Does anyone have any experience with this API call? My next step is to write the C equivalent and make sure I can get it working without interop.

My pinvoke declaration is:

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetGlyphIndicesW")> _
Private Shared Function GetGlyphIndices(ByVal hDC As IntPtr, 
                                        ByVal Text As String, 
                                        ByVal Count As Int32, 
     <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> ByVal Indices() As UInt16, 
                                        ByVal Mode As Int32) As Int32

End Function
```

I have tried variations on this to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ?

```
<DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetGlyphIndicesW")> _
Public Shared Function GetGlyphIndicesW( _
    <InAttribute()> ByVal hdc As System.IntPtr, _
    <InAttribute(), MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpstr As String, _
    ByVal c As Integer, _
    <OutAttribute()> ByRef pgi As UShort, _
    ByVal fl As UInteger) As UInteger
```

Comment: Bit late at night here but a quick test confirms this is returning correct result. 

Thank you very much!

I guess the question is why the original is incorrect. The purpose of this call is to look up glyph index for use in creating a PDF. Looks as though it may be a slow process if I cannot get multi-character version working!

Answer (score 0):

Further tests show that

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetGlyphIndicesW")> _
Private Shared Function GetGlyphIndices(ByVal hdc As System.IntPtr, _
                                      <MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpstr As String, _
                                      ByVal c As UInteger, _
                                      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)> ByVal Indices() As UInt16, ByVal Mode As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function
```

Works to return array of glyph indices for a string. The key attribute to getting this working is `MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPTStr` on the string. My own stupidity in thinking that strings were marshalled automatically (throwback to VB6?).

Note that GetGlyphIndices only works with Unicode returning 1-2 bytes. Fortunately Chinese/Japanese can be handled using built-in CMAP in PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The original declaration was incorrect because you explicitly targeted the Unicode version of the API by setting EntryPoint="GetGlyphIndicesW", while not specifying a character encoding and therefore using the default which is ANSI. So you get a Unicode/ANSI mismatch.

The easiest way to fix the problem would be to change your DllImport attribute to

```
<DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
```